# Object won't append to field array with react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm trying to set up a form with react-hook-form (which is amazing by the way) to input a TV series where the series has an arbitrary number of seasons and each season has an arbitrary number of episodes. I know I need to have seasons as a field array, but since it doesn't seem possible to create a new field array for each season, I've created a separate episodes field array which will hold an array of objects including a "season" key so I can identify and filter which episodes belong to which season. It's possible theres a better way to set this up altogether and that might be the real problem here.

With what I have set up though, I'm running into an issue where I need to keep values in the react-hook-form hook that won't be shown on the page as part of the form like the index of the episode (so I can update it in the field array without mapping through all episodes) and the season number it belongs to. When I try to append an episode to the episodes field array though, it doesn't update properly and episodes is undefined after the first episode is appended or only keeps the value of registered fields after any subsequent appends. Definitely seems to me that this has something to do with fields in episodes not being registered as part of the form, but in my case not all fields can be part of the form. Wondering if anyone has an idea for how to work with this problem or get around out, maybe with using actual react state while keeping renders at a minimum.

Code sandbox here

https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-browser-7ppf1

Expected behavior of above: after adding a season, add multiple episodes and see "episode number" move up incrementally in the UI and see all episode information in the console after submit.

EDIT:
I'm porting over code from React where the state was like

```
seriesState = {
  seriesTitle: "New TV Series"
  seasons: [
    {
      seasonTitle: "Season 1",
      seasonNumber: 1,
      episodes: [
        {
        episodeNumber: 1,
        title: "Season 1 Episode 1"
        },
        {
        episodeNumber: 2
        title: "Season 1 Episode 2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      seasonTitle: "Season 2",
      seasonNumber: 2,
      episodes: [
        {
        episodeNumber: 1,
        title: "Season 2 Episode 1"
        },
        {
        episodeNumber: 2,
        title: "Season 2 Episode 2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and trying to rewrite it for react-hook-form by rewriting it like below

```
seriesState = {
  seriesTitle: "New TV Series"
  seasons: [
    {
      number: 1,
      seasonTitle: "Season 1"
    },
    {
      number: 2,
      seasonTitle: "Season 2"
    }
  ],
  episodes: [
    {
      seasonNumber: 1,
      episodeNumber: 1
      episodeTitle: "season 1 episode 1"
    },
    {
      seasonNumber: 1,
      episodeNumber: 2
      episodeTitle: "season 1 episode 2"
    },
    {
      seasonNumber: 2,
      episodeNumber: 1
      episodeTitle: "season 2 episode 1"
    },
        {
      seasonNumber: 2,
      episodeNumber: 2
      episodeTitle: "season 2 episode 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

and now I'm changing it to

Comment: I took a glance at the code, and i can say you're doing things that are quite unconventional when using react. You're over engineering your code which makes it hard to help you. I would suggest you to look at some react documentation on how to handle forms, etc.

Comment: is this what you after? https://react-hook-form.com/api#useFieldArray

Comment: good point on the over engineering, just simplified the code a little bit

Comment: yes I am trying to use useFieldArray but don't think it is possible to use doubly nested arrays like seasons[0].episodes[0].title to access the title of season 1 episode 1 since I would have to create a FieldArray for the episodes in each season. 

When I separate the episodes and seasons field like in my codepen, the episodes don't append properly I think because I'm using unregistered fields to keep track of what season an episode belongs to.

Just updated my original question to add more information about the structure I want

Comment: yes possible: take a look at this folder: https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/tree/master/example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-usefieldarray-nested-arrays-x7btr

Comment: ah that's perfect, thanks for commenting! don't know how I didn't see that before with all the searches I made. I'm so used to keeping react state in a parent component it didn't come to me that I can use separate components and provide a ref to the hook. thanks for doing such great work with rhf too